# .vbs file, System can't find path

Tags: vbscript

Anyone knows why doesn't this work? It should open my .py file on background but I keep getting "cant find path" error..

```
Dim WShell
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShell.Run "MTFbot.py", 0
Set WShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Add [python](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) to %path%?

Comment: Give full path to MTFbot.py file